# Sublime Text 3 - Regex Replace Using Conditional Match

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

In Notepad++, it is possible to use this kind of expression in the "*Replace*" box:

```
(?{1}{$1}\n:)
```

This means *if first group matches, replace by first group followed by new line, else replace by empty string*.

Is this also possible in Sublime Text 3, and if yes, what is the exact syntax?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not implemented. It's a Boost feature and I think ST uses its own regex engine.

Comment: Yep, what I read is that the "parsing" is engine-specific but the "replacing" is implemented differently for each application, so was wondering if I got the syntax wrong or if it just did not exist in ST.

Comment: It is kind of obvious, but you can always run two regex commands. In my experience, I always found it easier to run multiple simpler regex operations, rather than combining all of them in one ubiquitous operation. (My two cents.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this since it's coming up in the top search results.

**If you need to write a snippet** to replace characters, you can:

- Use the regular regex syntax:
  `string/pattern/replacement/flags`
  eg. `"${SELECTION/\\s//g}"` to remove spaces in the selection
- Use the [Perl regex condition syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html), much harder to understand in my opinion; you have to group your patterns and then refer to them later, like so:
  `string/(group1)/(?1true-expression:false-expression)` where the `1` is for the first group of parenthesis, 2 would be for the second one, etc.
  eg. `"${TM_FILENAME/(.*\\.)(py|sh)|(.*)/(?2#:\\/\\/)(?3:)/} TODO - "` is used to add a comment with "`TODO -`" after a `#` if the file extension is `.py` or `.sh`, or two slashes (`//`) if not.

In the [Sublime Text documentation for variable substitution](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#variable-substitution), the more general [Perl regex syntax documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) is also provided, it could be useful to some people (there is a section about conditional expressions).

**If you're just trying to use the Find and Replace box** (`Ctrl+H` for me), then it's pretty straightforward, just activate regex (`Alt+R` for me), fill in the pattern you're looking for and leave the Replace box empty to remove what you don't want.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I can perform that search and replace in Notepad++, and I want to know if that can be done using Find and Replace in ST.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to address the actual question… you sure can! Once you activated regex in Find and Replace you can wrap your pattern in parentheses in the Find box: `(pattern)`, and refer to it with `\1` in the Replace box. So the replace box should look like `\1\n` in your case. Hope it helps :)
Edit: Ah, just saw you want to remove everything that's not your pattern. Not sure how to do that, I will check it out